# bootstrap 5.1.3 and custom CSS borders

Tags: html, css

I can't see the table's borders, but when I remove the bootstrap link

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it works fine.
Now what is going on?  I don't understand why can't I use custom borders and bootstrap at same time, it used to be possible in older versions, and I need the new version for some features.

```css
td {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-size: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: im trying to make a simple tic tac toe game, and i swear this works on older version on the tutorial im following, now how can i make it work on newer bootstrap version

Comment: Idk if this is bad practice, but you can add an `!important` behind every attribute so it gets "overwritten".

Comment: It's most likely CSS specificity. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. Your rules get overridden by Bootstrap's which are more specific. Just make yours as (or more) specific than theirs, and load yours last. Oh, and avoid using `!important`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the css to from td {} to table td{}  . Its not a good practice to use !important

```
    table td {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-size: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add an `!important` at the end of the attribute you try to change.
It solves the Problem but its not the best Practice to use...
But in cases like overwriting CSS from Bootstrap etc. its an easy way to overwrite any other CSS, no matter where it was declared.

```css
td{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black !important;
  font-size: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
     <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```